# Global Fibrations are Local Fibration in Local Injecive model Structure

Tags: model-categories

Suppose $T$ is a small site with enough points and $\Delta^{op}Shv(T)$ is the category of simplicial sheaves on $T$ endowed with local injective model structure. Here a map $f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ in $\Delta^{op}Shv(T)$ is weak equivalence if for each point $x^*$ of $T$, $x^{*}(f):x^*(\mathcal{X}) \to x^*(\mathcal{Y})$ is weak equivalence between simplicial sets, cofibrations are monomorphisms and fibrations are defined as right lifting property with respect to trivial cofibrations. Then is it true that if a map $f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ in $\Delta^{op}Shv(T)$ is fibration then for each point $x^*$ of $T$, the map $x^{*}(f):x^*(\mathcal{X}) \to x^*(\mathcal{Y})$ is a Kan fibration between simplicial sets? What about the converse? A priori I can't see any relation between fibration and local fibration. Please help with solution or if there is any good reference.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Every morphism of simplicial sheaves that has the right lifting property with respect to all monic weak equivalences is also a local Kan fibration.
This is true for general sites, though one has to define things differently if there are not enough points.
The converse is false.

Consider the simplicial global sections functor $\Gamma$, defined on simplicial sheaves by applying the usual global sections functor degreewise.
The usual global sections functor has a left adjoint, so the same is true of the simplicial global sections functor – call the left adjoint $\Delta$.
It is easy to check that, for every point $p$ of the topos, the composite $p^* \Delta$ is (isomorphic to) the identity functor on the category of simplicial sets.
Thus, $\Delta$ sends weak homotopy equivalences of simplicial sets to weak equivalences of simplicial sheaves.
In particular, $\Delta$ sends every horn inclusion $\Lambda^n_k \hookrightarrow \Delta^n$ to a monic weak equivalence of simplicial sheaves.
(If the site does not have enough points, a different argument is needed here, but the conclusion is the same.)

More generally, given a sheaf $U$ and a simplicial sheaf $X$, taking degreewise hom-sets yields a simplicial set $\textrm{Hom} (U, X)$, and the evident functor $\textrm{Hom} (U, -)$ has a left adjoint, namely $\Delta (-) \times U$.
Again, $\Delta (-) \times U$ sends weak homotopy equivalences of simplicial sets to weak equivalences of simplicial sheaves.

Now, suppose $f : X \to Y$ is a morphism of simplicial sheaves that has the right lifting property with respect to all monic weak equivalences.
In particular, it has the right lifting property with respect to every $\Delta (\Lambda^n_k) \times U \hookrightarrow \Delta (\Delta^n) \times U$.
Thus, by adjunction, every $\textrm{Hom} (U, f) : \textrm{Hom} (U, X) \to \textrm{Hom} (U, Y)$ has the right lifting property with respect to every $\Lambda^n_k \hookrightarrow \Delta^n$, i.e. is a Kan fibration of simplicial sets.

Let $Z (U)$ be the set of all commmutative diagrams of the form below:
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\Delta (\Lambda^n_k) \times U & @>>> X \\
@VVV & @VV{f}V  \\
\Delta (\Delta^n) \times U @>>> Y
\end{CD}
\tag{$*$}$$
(The arrow in the left column is the canonical one.)
This defines a contravariant functor from the category of sheaves to the category of sets, and it is easy to check that it is representable.
Abusing notation somewhat, let $Z$ denote the sheaf representing it.
There is a canonical commutative diagram of the form below,
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\Delta (\Lambda^n_k) \times Z & @>>> X \\
@VVV & @VV{f}V  \\
\Delta (\Delta^n) \times Z @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$
corresponding to the universal element in $Z (Z)$.
(Recall the definition of representable functor!)
But $f : X \to Y$ has the right lifting property with respect to $\Delta (\Lambda^n_k) \times Z \hookrightarrow \Delta (\Delta^n) \times Z$, so we get a diagonal filler for this diagram.
This $\Delta (\Delta^n) \times Z \to X$ is universal in the following sense: commutative diagrams of the form $(*)$ are in natural bijection with morphisms $U \to Z$, and the natural bijection extends to diagonal fillers as well.

The construction of $Z$ depends on $f : X \to Y$ and $\Lambda^n_k \hookrightarrow \Delta^n$, but in such a way that it can be expressed using only limits of finite diagrams.
Thus, this construction is preserved by the inverse image functor of any geometric morphism.
In particular, for any point $p$, we get universal fillers for the morphism $p^* f : p^* X \to p^* Y$, so $p^* f : p^* X \to p^* Y$ is a Kan fibration of simplicial sets.
Hence $f : X \to Y$ is a local Kan fibration, as claimed.
(Again, a different argument is needed if there are not enough points, but the conclusion is the same.)

Comment: please mention what is $\Delta$ functor i.e. right adjoint of $Hom(U,X)$ ? And $Hom(U,X)$ is the simplicial set defined as $n \mapsto Hom(U, X_n)$ right?

Comment: Why $\Delta$ preserves weak equivalence?

Comment: $\Delta$ is the left adjoint of $\Gamma$. It preserves weak equivalences by the argument in the second paragraph.

Comment: What is global section functor in a general site? Is it evaluation at terminal object on site? Why $p^*\Delta$ is isomorphic to identity functor on simplicial sets?

Comment: Yes, global sections is $\textrm{Hom} (1, -)$. $p^* \Delta$ is isomorphic to the identity functor because it is defined degreewise and it preserves $1$ and coproducts degreewise. Forgive me for saying this, but if this is not obvious to you then you are probably not ready to study the homotopy theory of simplicial sheaves.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt again, I am a beginner. You are saying points on a site take constant sheaf to that corresponding set i.e  the functor $Sets \to Sets$ defined as $A \mapsto x^*(A)$, where the right side $A$ is the constant sheaf $A$ is isomorphic to identity functor for any point $x^*$ on the site.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I can't get the proof why $A \mapsto x^*(A)$ is isomorphic to identity functor.

Comment: This is indeed true for sheaf on topological space since stalks are the set $A$ but for general site I can't prove it.

Comment: You have a composite of inverse image functors of geometric morphisms, so it preserves $1$ and coproducts. There is only one such functor (up to isomorphism) $\textbf{Set} \to \textbf{Set}$. That's all there is to it.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: Sir please explain last paragraph why this diagram has lift:$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\Lambda^n_k & @>>> p^*X \\
@VVV & @VV{p^*f}V  \\
\Delta^n @>>> p^*Y
\end{CD}$$

Comment: Such a diagram corresponds to an element of $p^* Z$. We have a universal filler $\Delta^n \times p^* Z \to p^* X$ and this specialises to the required filler $\Delta^n \to p^* X$.

Comment: Why such diagram correspond to an element of $p^*Z$.. so corresponding to given diagram  we need to get a diagram $$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
\Delta (\Lambda^n_k) & @>>> X \\
@VVV & @VV{f}V  \\
\Delta (\Delta^n)  @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$ If I apply $\Delta$ on given diagram, we need to give map from $\Delta p^*(X) \to X$. How to get this map please tell me ..

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not something that can be explained in the space of a comment. It is straightforward if you know category theory and are well practised in standard arguments. Writing a detailed explanation for a beginner is hard and I'm not really in the mood to do so.